# How to share data between forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Consider two forms: form1 and form2

`form1` calls `form2`:

```
form2 frm = new form2()
frm.show
```

`form2` shows a grid with data. When data is selected, it's put into a textbox.

I need the return value from `form2` to `form1` when it's closed.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `public` property to your `Form2` class that returns the selected item.

Then, replace the `Show()` call with `ShowDialog()` (a blocking method) and check the property afterwards.

Also, rename your forms.

Answer (score 0):

if you change Modifiers Property of a control in a Form to Public, another Forms can access to that control. 
f.e. :

```
Form2 frm; 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    frm = new Form2(); 
    frm.Show(); 
} 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(frm.txtUserName.Text); 
    //txtUserName is a TextBox with Modifiers=Public
}
```