# How to make a variable that will work on multiple forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, variables

Right now I have 2 forms. I would like to make a variable (Like a int) that will pass between the 2 forms. For instance, I make a variable on the first form with the code: `public static int myInt = 50;`
But how to I transfer that variable to form 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Sharing data between forms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800603/1497596)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first form you should have (Assuming you're using the designer)

```
//Form1.cs
namespace myProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int myInt = 50;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

To access in your second form, assuming they are in the same namespace, use:

```
//Form2.cs
namespace myProject
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        int thisInt;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            thisInt = Form1.myInt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am a newbie to C#. How do I get them into the same namespace?

Comment: They should automatically be in the same namespace. When you make a project the namespace has the same name as the project, and generally every form is put into it (tested just to make sure, works fine for me)

Comment: Okay, So I just tried the code and it gave me an error on form 2. It says "Form 1 does not contain definition for myInt"

Comment: It turns out I had the code in the wrong place! Works now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Don't create any static or public variable like that... You should create a property in second form that you can access from first form. though you can transfer your value directly in your second form without declaring any static variable.

```
//Form2

private string value1 = string.Empty;
public string Value1
{
   get { return value1; }
   set { value1 = value; }
}


//Form1

private void YourMethod()
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Value1 = "This is a sample value to pass in form 2";
    frm.Show();

}
```

Now, you can get value in Form2 by using `Value` property.

```
//Form2
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string myValue = Value1; //here you can use value like that
}
```

Comment: What's the problem of using a Static variable? It seems to be more readable and easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the constructor for form 2 to accept the variable and pass it from form 1.

```
public Form2(int passed)
```

If you want to pass it by reference then.

```
public Form2(ref int passed)
```

To open Form 2 with the variable by reference.

```
int passed = 1;
new Form2(ref passed);
```

If passed by reference, if the value is changed in form 2 that change will also show up in form 1 because "is the same" variable (same value in memory).