# pass data between two forms in c#

Tags: c#

I have a form with a button, when the button is clicked, the `[public int m = 0]` changes 1. I have another form `[form2]`, when I make a new class from `form1` to get `m` value, it passes `0` and I don't know why.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int m =0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        m = 1;

    }

}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{

Form2 form2_new = new Form2();

// methods to get m ---------> it should be 1 but I get 0!!!!

}
```

Comment: There is a wealth of Q&A on this topic already. This post is surely a duplicate of at least one, if not many, of those here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+pass+data+between+two+forms

Comment: google is your best friend. There are literally tons of the same question with answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a variable that will work on multiple forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337534/how-to-make-a-variable-that-will-work-on-multiple-forms)

Answer (score 1):

Inside Form2 make a new constructor:

```
public int m;
public Form2(int m)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.m = m;
}
```

And then from Form1 call Form2 and pass the value:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m = 1;

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(m);
    frm2.Show();
}
```