# How to transfer text from textBox in Form1 to label in Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

As the titles says, I have problem with trasnfering data.(I'm using vs 2019 windows forms)

I tried following instructions on other tutorials and question on stackOverflow but it didn't work.
So please can you help me with my problem. I tried something it is in the code the public static string but it does not work.  Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace InventoryApp
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Tim\source\repos\InventoryApp1\InventoryApp\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static string User = "";
        private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from registration where username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password = '" + txtPsw.Text + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

            if (i == 0) // če ne vrne ničesar (podatek ne obstaja)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Username and Password does not match");
                txtUsername.Text = ""; // resetira polje v prazno
                txtPsw.Text = ""; // resetira polje v prazno
                txtUsername.Focus(); // focus na Username
            }
            else
            {
                User = txtUsername.Text;
                this.Hide();
                home h = new home(); // v mdi shrani index stran (home)
                h.Show(); // prikaže index stran (Home)              
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();

            }
            con.Open();
        }

        private void labelX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace InventoryApp
{
    public partial class home : Form
    {

        public home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*Form childForm = new Form();
            childForm.MdiParent = this;
            childForm.Text = "Window " + childFormNumber++;
            childForm.Show();*/
        }

        private void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void SaveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string FileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ExitToolsStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void CopyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void PasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ToolBarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // toolStrip.Visible = toolBarToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
        }

        private void StatusBarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  statusStrip.Visible = statusBarToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
        }

        private void CascadeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
        }

        private void TileVerticalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
        }

        private void TileHorizontalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
        }

        private void ArrangeIconsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.ArrangeIcons);
        }

        private void CloseAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Form childForm in MdiChildren)
            {
                childForm.Close();
            }
        }

        private void addNewUserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add_new_user anu = new add_new_user(); //shranim v spremenljivko (add_new_user stran)
            anu.Show(); // odpre stran "add_new_user"
        }

        private void addNewUnitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Unit un = new Unit(); //shranim v spremenljivko (Unit stran)
            un.Show(); // odpre stran "Unit"
        }

        private void userToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void addNewProductToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add_product_name apn = new add_product_name(); // iz index strani poveze na okno "Add New Product"

            apn.Show(); // prikaze okno
        }

        private void addNewSupplierToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            supplier_info si = new supplier_info(); // iz index strani poveze na okno "Supplier Information"

            si.Show(); // prikaze okno
        }

        private void purchaseFromSupplierToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            purchase_product pfs = new purchase_product(); // iz index strani poveze na okno "Purchase Product"            

            pfs.Show(); // prikaze okno
        }

        private void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Tim\source\repos\InventoryApp1\InventoryApp\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

                string sqlStr = "SELECT product_quantity, product_name from stock ";

                SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConnection); 
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                myCommand.Fill(ds);

                DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);

                chartStock.DataSource = source;

                chartStock.Series[0].XValueMember = "product_name";
                chartStock.Series[0].YValueMembers = "product_quantity";
                chartStock.DataBind();
        }

        private void buttonAddNewUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add_new_user anu = new add_new_user(); //shranim v spremenljivko (add_new_user stran)
            anu.Show(); // odpre stran "add_new_user"
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void buttonAddNewUnit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Unit un = new Unit(); //shranim v spremenljivko (Unit stran)
            un.Show(); // odpre stran "Unit"
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void buttonAddNewSupplier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            supplier_info si = new supplier_info(); // iz index strani poveze na okno "Supplier Information"
            si.Show(); // prikaze okno
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void buttonAddNewProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add_product_name apn = new add_product_name(); // iz index strani poveze na okno "Add New Product"
            apn.Show(); // prikaze okno
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void buttonPurchaseProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            purchase_product pfs = new purchase_product(); // iz index strani poveze na okno "Purchase Product"            
            pfs.Show(); // prikaze okno
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void buttonLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            login l = new login();
            l.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void labelX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void buttonDashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelUser.Text = login.User;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post:
[How to make a variable that will work on multiple forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337534/how-to-make-a-variable-that-will-work-on-multiple-forms)

I think the link above is what you are after.

Otherwise... Based on the title of this post... If you just want to send textbox text to a label in another form...

in Form 2 set your Label to Public in it's properties.

[image]

Once the modifiers are set to public it can take values from outside of itself.

Next in Form1 i added this code to a button click event.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.label1.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
        frm2.ShowDialog();
        frm2.Close();
    }
```

This takes the text in the textbox of Form1 and places it in the label of Form2.

Comment: Static variables can be changed outside of the class.

Comment: @3.473.632 - Did the link i put in my post help you or did my answer help?  Either way, I'm glad you were able to find a solution!

Comment: @Crowcoder - I must be mistaken... how do you access a static variable outside of it's class?

Comment: You access a static variable with the class name instead of a class instance <your class>.<your variable>