# How to use array in two different forms?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use one array that I declared in one form, to plot a graph with zedgraph, in a different form.

How do I need to declare the array and where?

Comment: No different than using/accessing any object (e.g. through properties or other exchange) from a different Form .. it's also mostly irrelevant of how said object is used.

Comment: You should take a closer look at the basics before going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800603/sharing-data-between-forms (and several others, follow links)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't declare your array in the first form.

Declare it in a separate component/class/whatever instead, and let both forms access the array there. That way, the array should be independent of the forms, and both can use it.