# Preventing an object referenced by another form being destroyed upon child form termination

Tags: c#, winforms, garbage-collection

I have the following problem: An array of chart Series is passed from one form to another to be visualized in the child form i do this in order to enlarge the viewing area of a chart i have in my main window. It all works fine until i close the second form to which my Series have been passed at this point my application crushes an a null object reference is raised. Now I suspect my Series have been garbage collected upon that form termination. Any Ideas how this can be fixed and safely close that form without destroying the data?

Here is the code leading to the creation of the form.

```
Series[] tpSeries = { chart2.Series["S1"], chart2.Series["S2"] };

Dictionary<string, NumericUpDown> netParams = new Dictionary<string, NumericUpDown>()
{ 
 {"N", numVertecies},
 {"S", numS},
 {"R", numR},
 {"Gamma", numGama},
 {"Beta", numBeta},
 {"G", numG},
 {"C0", numCzero},
};

TimePlotAnalysis tpForm = new TimePlotAnalysis(tpSeries, netParams); // N, s, r, gamma, beta, g, c_0 
tpForm.Show();
```

Comment: Can you explain in further detail how the Series array is being passed?

Comment: Instead of passing `SeriesCollection` or `Series`, pass the data you want to show in other form.

Comment: I have added the code creating the second form to my original post. The thing is that the data is stored in the Series themselves. i didn't wanna copy it out into a separate structure just so i can pass it over and then create new Series object from it.

Comment: *REAL SIMPLE*: you should wrap your series (or better, the data you want to display in your series) *IN ITS OWN, SEPARATE, CLASS*. You can instantiate the class in one or another form. You can also create a static method to let the class instantiate an instance of itself (the "singleton" pattern I alluded to before. You *define the data* OUTSIDE of the form; you *share* the data BETWEEN forms. There are several different examples in the link below

Comment: _I suspect my Series have been garbage collected ..._  cannot be the cause of null-ref exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your data should be in a *separate* class, then you simply share a class instance between forms.

There are many different ways to do this, depending on your particular use case.  Here are a few examples:

- [How to share data between forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800603/how-to-share-data-between-forms)
- [To Pass Values between two forms using C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ef14e60-28fb-43d5-9c10-14463444d2e3/to-pass-values-between-two-forms-using-c?forum=winforms)
- http://colinmackay.scot/2005/04/22/passing-values-between-forms-in-net/

Depending on your specific requirements, you might want to implement this object as a "singleton":

- http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Now I suspect my Series have been garbage collected upon that form termination.

The issue has nothing in common with GC. You pass array of `Series` **objects** taken from a chart control in one form to another form, where (although you didn't show) I suspect you add them to another chart control.

Let take a look at `Series` class  [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series(v=vs.110).aspx).

> **Inheritance Hierarchy**
>   System.Object
>     System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElement
>       System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartNamedElement
>         System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCustomProperties
>           System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series

Following the hierarchy, here is the base class definition

```
public abstract class ChartElement : IDisposable
```

Note the `IDisposable`? Now I guess you understand what is happening. When you close the second form, the `Dispose` method is called on the form and all the controls. The correct dispose implementations will in turn call dispose on any disposable object they hold (and we can assume MS controls **do** correctly implement the disposable pattern).

Shortly, I think the `Series` objects passed to the second form are disposed.

To fix the problem, as [Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) correctly pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537994/preventing-an-object-referenced-by-another-form-being-destroyed-upon-child-form#comment56818475_34537994), you should not pass `Series` objects to the second form, but the data that allows them to be recreated there. Or at least make sure you really create a **new** `Series` **objects** from the ones you pass.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll definitely do it that way in the future project, but since this is already written in this messy way I found a clean solution to patch it up, simply create an even listener for the form closing and use Series.clear() that seems to work like a charm.