# update 2 different label with same output from 2 different forms simultaneously

Tags: c#, winforms

i have 2 forms they both have label1, form1 and form2 label1 must show the same output, when i click a button on form1 the label1 in form1 will change so as the label1 in form2

Form1

```
        SqlDataReader reader = cmdnext.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            label1.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            break;

        }
        sqlcon.Close();

        Lobbypage lp = new Lobbypage(label1.Text);

    }
```

Form2

```
     public Lobbypage(string labelText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = labelText;

    }
```

skip button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdcurrent = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
        cmdcurrent.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdcurrent.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = title;
        cmdcurrent.CommandText = "update tblQLCashier set status = 'missing' where queID = (select min(queID) from tblQLCashier where status = 'On process' and department = @Title)";
        cmdcurrent.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand cmdnext = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
        cmdnext.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdnext.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = title;
        cmdnext.CommandText = "update tblQLCashier set status = 'On process' , department = @Title where queID = (select min(queID) from tblQLCashier where status = 'Pending' and department ='')";
        cmdnext.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlcon.Close();

        sqlcon.Open();
        cmdnext.CommandText = "select queID from tblQLCashier where queID = (select min(queID) from tblQLCashier where department in ('', @Title) and status in ('Pending', 'On process'))";
        SqlDataReader reader = cmdnext.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            label1.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            break;

        }
        sqlcon.Close();

        Lobbypage lp = new Lobbypage(label1);

    }
```

both label1 in form1 and form2 should simultaneously update and have the same output

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800603/how-to-share-data-between-forms)

Comment: References are your friend

Comment: What do you do with the newly created `Lobbypage` (variable `lp`) ? Is it discarded ?

Answer (score 1):

In Form2

```
public Lobbypage(Label label)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1 = label;
}
```

In Form1

```
Lobbypage lp = new Lobbypage(label1);
```

So what's going on ? When giving `label1` in `Lobbypage`'s constructor, it creates a new variable (`label`) which is a copy of `label1`. The "trick" is that `label1` is in fact a reference thus the copy will also point to the same label object.

Comment: my prob here is that when i click the skip button the label here in the form1 will change number but in the other form its still the same its still 9 i need to close the form2 and open it again for it to update

Comment: @vantesleo Did you try my approach ?

Comment: yes, sir still not working only the label in form1 incremented and form2 is still 9

Comment: @vantesleo Can you post the event handler called when Skip button is pressed ?

Comment: sorry im new with programming are you asking the skip button code? i already edited my post and add the skip code. ty

Answer (score 1):

you can create one **static string property** and assign it to both labels.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u make a public label this is the code that works for me:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    static public Label label2 = new Label();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        Controls.Add(label2);
        label2.Text = "mama";
    }
}
}
```

the other Form

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {

        Form2 hi = new Form2();
        hi.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.label2.Text = "Mathman";

    }
}
}
```

Be sure to add the functions to the handler. that means not just copy paste it in. Dubble click on the form to add the loadfunction automatically
[after Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx2NZ.png)
[before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok9xA.png)